# How can I remotely reboot ubuntu if the shutdown command is broken?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I have a remote ubuntu box that I need to reboot. When I issue `sudo reboot`, `sudo shutdown -r now` or `init 6`, or just about any other equivelant, I get:

```
root@hostname:/home/administrator# sudo shutdown -r now
shutdown: invalid option: -r
Try `shutdown --help' for more information.
```

Is there any way in which I could get this machine to reboot via another means? I don't have physical access to it.

Comment: I know that I could spend hours trying to address ***why*** the shutdown command won't work, but time is of the essence at this point. Just need to get it to reboot. Unless, of course, it's impossible otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify -- you're getting that same error when typing init 6?

Comment: Yes. Same exact error for all methods of rebooting, including `init 6`

Comment: Wow. I might check to verify that the correct init or shutdown executables are being called. Does the command:
`which shutdown` show the path to the correct shutdown command?  It's odd that init gives that same error.

Comment: `which shutdown` returns: `/sbin/shutdown`, which appears correct.

Comment: If it's Ubuntu 15.04 or higher, you can try this:
`systemctl reboot`

Comment: Tried that as well. Unfortunately, same exact error.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to shutdown the system normally and use WOL (Wake On LAN) to boot it back up. Before you do so you should make sure it is enabled by following this guide: http://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/ start from the "Linux" section and follow the instructions to enable it. I can confirm this works on Ubuntu Server 15.10 as I have just done so and successfully booted it up from my Android device. However I am on the same LAN as the server so YMMV but I'm certain it is possible. Good Luck

Comment: How can I "shut down the system normally" in the context of my question?

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized you are unable to use the shutdown command. My bad.